# SolrNet retrieving a field value in Sitefinity MVC view

Tags: solr, sitefinity, solrnet

I am using Solr for internal Search and also for filtering content items in my Sitefinity MVC. I am creating a View for a list of events, the View will be used to render the Search results of my Solr widget.

My Event content type has a field for "Summary", which is a **Long text (text area)** type. More about filed types in Sitefinity can be found here:
https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/use-custom-fields-in-widget-templates-dp

For some reason, I can pull any other field values and display them in my View, except for the "Summary" field.

For **Short text** fields I used `@item.getStringField("State")` and it works fine.

For my **Long text (editor)** fields, which are HTML content, I used `@Html.Raw(item.getHtmlField("Agenda"))` and they also work fine, so I thought I can do the same with "Summary" field but this `@Html.Raw(item.getHtmlField("Summary"))` does not return any value.

How does Solr see **Long text (text area)** different than **Long text (editor)** or **Short text**? Do I need a different method other than `getHtmlField()` for **Long text (text area)** fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sitefinity MVC views you can access the fields through item.Fields.FieldName.
And in details view you use Model.Item.Fields.FieldName

Here is an example for the Summary field in the listing view:

```
@Html.HtmlSanitize((string)item.Fields.Summary)
```

In the details view you can get the Summary using the below:

```
@Html.HtmlSanitize((string)Model.Item.Fields.Summary)
```

You will need to add the below using statement:

```
@using Telerik.Sitefinity.Frontend.Mvc.Helpers
```

Comment: Hi Sabrie, I do have this using statement in my view, but using this @Html.HtmlSanitize((string)item.Fields.Summary) broke my view. Checking the log files now to see what happened.

Comment: From the log files: RD.SolrNet.ContentItem' does not contain a definition for 'Fields' and no extension method 'Fields' accepting a first argument of type 'RD.SolrNet.ContentItem' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Then I removed 'Fields' and did this: <p>@Html.HtmlSanitize((string)item.Summary)</p> but this is not returning the summary content. It returns a blank <p> tag.

Comment: Just a side note, there are methods in SolrNet/ContentItems.cs of my project and public string getHtmlField(string fieldName) is one of them. This is how the other Html fields are accessed in the View, but for some reason I cannot access Summary with the same method.

Comment: ok, you have some custom logic there.
In your ContentItems.cs where you get the items and their fields, you should be able to get the item Summary value through GetValue("Summary"):    

var summary = sfContentItem.GetValue("Summary");  

You will need to add the following using statement for the GetValue() to work: @using Telerik.Sitefinity.Model;